# managing resources on a debian server

Tags: debian, memory-management

We have a debian server shared by all group members to run their memory/cpu (64GB RAM and 23 cores) intensive codes on it.  The problem is sometime one code overload the whole server and no one else is able to do anything. I want to ask if there is any known solution for that? for example limiting the amount of memory use by each user and killing the process if it goes beyond the limit? any better suggestion?

Comment: You could talk to each other, or get a bigger server (or two)

Comment: Can you see what it is doing when no one can log in to the system using a logged in user?

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. You will be able to limit resources by user or group (ie: max number of opened files, memory limit and so on...).

User will be able to see his "limits" by running `ulimit -a`. If you specify a soft limit for him, he will be able to change it using this same command.

You can also change the `nice` priority of their process.

See:

```
man ulimit
man limits.conf
```